# Sort Map<DateTime, double> Flutter, Dart

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart

I got a Map<DateTime, double> I want the keys to be sorted by time with the right double values.
How do I do that?
PS:
I get the DateTime and double values seperatly with 2 lists where DateTime[1] is the double at [1] and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`SplayTreeMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-collection/SplayTreeMap-class.html) for this if you want the keys in your map to be sorted in a specific way:

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  final sortedMap = SplayTreeMap<DateTime, double>();

  sortedMap[DateTime(2021, 1, 1)] = 1.0;
  sortedMap[DateTime(2021, 1, 3)] = 3.0;
  sortedMap[DateTime(2021, 1, 4)] = 4.0;
  sortedMap[DateTime(2021, 1, 2)] = 2.0;
  sortedMap[DateTime(2021, 1, 5)] = 5.0;

  sortedMap.entries.forEach(print);
  // MapEntry(2021-01-01 00:00:00.000: 1.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-02 00:00:00.000: 2.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-03 00:00:00.000: 3.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-04 00:00:00.000: 4.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-05 00:00:00.000: 5.0)
}
```

By default, it uses the `compareTo` method if the keys are comparable. You can also provide your own compare method like this if you e.g. want to change the order of the sorting:

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  final sortedMap = SplayTreeMap<DateTime, double>((a, b) => b.compareTo(a));

  sortedMap[DateTime(2021, 1, 1)] = 1.0;
  sortedMap[DateTime(2021, 1, 3)] = 3.0;
  sortedMap[DateTime(2021, 1, 4)] = 4.0;
  sortedMap[DateTime(2021, 1, 2)] = 2.0;
  sortedMap[DateTime(2021, 1, 5)] = 5.0;

  sortedMap.entries.forEach(print);
  // MapEntry(2021-01-01 00:00:00.000: 1.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-02 00:00:00.000: 2.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-03 00:00:00.000: 3.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-04 00:00:00.000: 4.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-05 00:00:00.000: 5.0)
}
```

And if you can also create a `SplayTreeMap` from another `Map`:

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  final inputMap = {
    DateTime(2021, 1, 1): 1.0,
    DateTime(2021, 1, 3): 3.0,
    DateTime(2021, 1, 4): 4.0,
    DateTime(2021, 1, 2): 2.0,
    DateTime(2021, 1, 5): 5.0,
  };

  final sortedMapA = SplayTreeMap<DateTime, double>.from(inputMap);
  final sortedMapB = SplayTreeMap<DateTime, double>.from(inputMap, (a, b) => b.compareTo(a));

  sortedMapA.entries.forEach(print);
  // MapEntry(2021-01-01 00:00:00.000: 1.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-02 00:00:00.000: 2.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-03 00:00:00.000: 3.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-04 00:00:00.000: 4.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-05 00:00:00.000: 5.0)

  sortedMapB.entries.forEach(print);
  // MapEntry(2021-01-05 00:00:00.000: 5.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-04 00:00:00.000: 4.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-03 00:00:00.000: 3.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-02 00:00:00.000: 2.0)
  // MapEntry(2021-01-01 00:00:00.000: 1.0)
}
```